# Why can't the python script get the post parameters from hunchentoot-cgi?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

The hunchentoot-cgi basically works with hunchentoot-1.2.2 now with a few modification:

1. In `#'handle-cgi-script`, replacing `:external-format tbnl::+latin-1+` with `:external-format tbnl::+utf-8+`
2. As WhiteCat suggested, use `#'make-pathname` as below:

   ```
   (pushnew (hunchentoot-cgi::create-cgi-dispatcher-and-handler
             "/cgi-bin/"
             (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "media" "E"
                                                   "myapp" "cgi-bin")))
            dispatch-table :test #'equal)
   ```

However, I do not understand why the python script cannot get the POSTed parameter, i.e., when visiting `http://127.0.0:8000/cgi-bin/login.py?cmd=view`, login.py can get the parameter `cmd`'s value sucessfully, but when posted by the following form, login.py cannot get all the posted values (no matter hidden or not):

```
<html><body>
  <form method='POST' action='cgi-bin/login.py'>
    <input type='text' name='userid'>
    <input type='password' name='userpwd'>
    <input type='submit' value='Login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='view'>
  </form>
</body></html>
```

I guess hunchentoot-cgi does not pass the posted parameter(s) to the python script according to the environment:

- `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/nav.py?userid=xyz&cmd=view`
  The environment passed to the python script is:

  ```
  (SERVER_SOFTWARE=hunchentoot/1.2.2
   SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1 GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
   SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1 SERVER_PORT=8000 REQUEST_METHOD=GET
   CONTENT_TYPE=text/html CONTENT_LENGTH=NIL
   SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/nav.py QUERY_STRING=userid=xyz&cmd=view
   REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1 HTTP_HOST=NIL
   REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/nav.py?userid=xyz&cmd=view SERVER_ADDR=NIL
   HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
   HTTP_REFERER=http://127.0.0.1:8000/)
  ```
- POST to `/cgi-bin/nav.py`

  ```
  (SERVER_SOFTWARE=hunchentoot/1.2.2
   SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1 GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
   SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1 SERVER_PORT=8000 REQUEST_METHOD=POST
   CONTENT_TYPE=text/html CONTENT_LENGTH=NIL
   POST_PARAMETERS=((userid . xyz) (userpwd . 123) (cmd . view))
   SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/nav.py QUERY_STRING=NIL REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1     
   HTTP_HOST=NIL REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/nav.py SERVER_ADDR=NIL
   HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
  ```

I think "CONTENT_LENGTH=NIL" is wrong, isnot it?

Please shed a light on me, thanks!

Comment: It says right there `POST_PARAMETERS=((userid . xys)...` . So, what's wrong?

Comment: POST_PARAMETERS are exported by hunchentoot and i add a format to show it. But hunchentoot-cgi cannot pass it to python script.

Comment: By adding "("CONTENT_TYPE" . ,(header-in :content-type *request*))
           ("CONTENT_LENGTH" . ,(parse-integer (header-in :content-length *request*)))"  to #'handle-cgi-script in hunchentoot-cgi.lisp, i get a right environment passed to the python script. However, the script still cannot get the passed post parameters.(lisp handler can get the posted parameters normally)

Answer (score 0):

After messy hacking of hunchentoot-cgi.lisp, it works now. However, wish it is helpful for Cyrus Harmon (http://cyrusharmon.org/blog) to release the next canonical version.

```
>diff cgi.lisp /media/E/RnD/clisp/hunchentoot-cgi/hunchentoot-cgi.lisp
71c71
<   (let ((time (or (file-write-date path) (get-universal-time))) (query-string (content-length nil))
---
>   (let ((time (or (file-write-date path) (get-universal-time))))
77,83d76
< (if (member (request-method *request*) *methods-for-post-parameters* :test #'eq)
<     (progn
<         (setq query-string (format nil "~{~A~^&~}" (mapcar (lambda (x) (format nil "~A=~A" (car x) (tbnl:url-encode (cdr x)))) (tbnl:post-parameters*))))
<         (setq content-length (parse-integer (header-in :content-length *request*)))
<     )
<     (setq query-string (tbnl:query-string*)))
< 
87c80,81
<                       . ,(format nil "hunchentoot/~A" hunchentoot-asd:*hunchentoot version*))
---
>                       . (format nil "hunchentoot/~A"
>                                 hunchentoot-asd:*hunchentoot-version*))
97c91,92
<                     #+nil ("REMOTE_HOST" . "FIXME!")
---
>                      ("QUERY_STRING" . ,(tbnl:query-string*))
>                      #+nil ("REMOTE_HOST" . "FIXME!")
101,106c96
<                      ("PATH" . ,(sb-unix::posix-getenv "PATH"))
<                      ("QUERY_STRING" . ,query-string)
<                      ("CONTENT_TYPE" . ,(header-in :content-type *request*))
<                      ("CONTENT_LENGTH" . ,content-length)
<                      ;("HTTP_COOKIE" . ,(tbnl:cookies-out*))
<                      ("HTTP_COOKIE" . "userid=xxx")
---
>                          
112,113c102,103
<                      ("HTTP_REFERER" . ,(tbnl:referer))))))
< (format t "ENV is ~A~%" env)
---
>                      ("HTTP_REFERER" . ,(tbnl:referer))))))      
>       
125c115
<           :external-format tbnl::+utf-8+)))
---
>           :external-format tbnl::+latin-1+)))                   
128d117
< (format t "ERROR: ~A~%" error)                   ("HTTP_REFERER" . (tbnl:referer))))))
< (format t "ENV is ~A~%" env)
```

Sincerely!

Comment: Now i use QUERY-STRING to pass the posted parameters to CGI app. It works but it should be better to use standard-input. Unfortunately i donot know how to hack hunchentoot-cgi to support it.

Answer (score 0):

old versions of hunchentoot-cgi didn't support CGI data at all. try 0.3 or later and file an issue on github if this still isn't fixed for you.